# My session ignore database results and not working

Tags: php, session, user-permissions

Firstly I must excuse for my bad English. I need help with my code to login.php because I´m doing a permission system trough sessions but this session called "$_SESSION['perms']" does not accepts database values. I´m searching couple of weeks to find an answer but unsuccessfully. And so I´m appeal here.

this is code of my login:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .odstavec {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root') or 
           die('could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());

    mysqli_select_db($dbc, 'loginsystem') or die('no db connection');

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['go'])){

      $usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, htmlentities($_POST['u_name']));
      $psw = ($_POST['u_pass']);

      $q = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$usr' AND password='$psw' ";  

      $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

      if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1){

        $_SESSION['log'] = 'in';
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['u_name'];
        $_SESSION['perms'] = "SELECT $usr FROM members WHERE perms='".$_SESSION['perms']."'";

        header('location:novinky.php');
      } 
      elseif(!$_POST['u_name'] || !$_POST['u_pass']){
      $error = 'Všechna pole musí být vyplněná!';
      }else{    //create an error message
      $error = 'Chybné jméno nebo heslo. Prosím zkuste to znovu';
      }  
    }  //end of isset go
    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form method="post" action="#">
    <p class="odstavec"><label for="u_name">Uživatlské jméno:</label></p>
    <p class="odstavec"><input type="text" name="u_name" value=""></p>

    <p class="odstavec"><label for="u_pass">Heslo:</label></p>

    <p class="odstavec"><input type="password" name="u_pass" value=""></p>

    <p><button type="submit" name="go">Přihlásit</button></p>
   </form>
<!-- A paragraph to display eventual errors -->
```

I am tried many of ways. But nothing work. Also there is my administration.php may be an error in it but I watched in this an progress.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <title>Administrace</title>
 </head>
 <?php
   session_start();

   if (isset($_SESSION['log']) && ($_SESSION['perms']=="3")){
     echo '<body>';
     echo '<div class="up_div">';
     echo '<img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px" src="../images/admin_up_div.png">';
     echo '<p style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px">Vítej '.$_SESSION["username"].'</p>';
     echo '</div>';
     echo '</body>';
   }
   elseif (isset($_SESSION['log']) && ($_SESSION['perms']=="1")){
     echo 'Omlouvám se, ale pro tuto sekci nemáte dostatečná oprávnění'; //Sorry message if they haven´t permissons
   header('location: novinky.php');
   }else{
   header('location: login.php');
   }
 ?>   
</html>
```

Beforehand I´m thanks for answers.

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection at `$psw = ($_POST['u_pass']);`

Answer (score 0):

Is the correct information in the database?  To make sure change...

```
 $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

to

```
 echo $usr."<br/>";
 echo $psw."<br/>";
 echo $q;
 exit();
 $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

What I think is happening is that your mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlentities is changing the user string so it no longer matches.

If its not obvious try running $q in the command line or phpmyadmin and see if any errors popup.

Also like orique said, you need to sanitize your password.

Comment: I researched more. I need that $_SESSION['perms'] to get values from database, no verify...